# Angular 8 keyup event taking too much time to call (first time)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 8. In my project there is one input field in which we call an function to search on keyup event. But this keyup event is not called at first time (after refresh).

For Example: First time open localhost:4200 in the browser and try to search any keyword like foo then application will take at least 8-9 seconds to call function filterVulnScheduleList and get the result in response. After getting this response now, if we try to search any other keyword like world then it'll give response in 400ms or less.

angular.html

`<input class="form-control border-right-0" name="searchScheduleList" #searchScheduleList placeholder="search" (keyup)="filterVulnScheduleList($event)">`

angular.ts

```
import { NbMenuItem, NbMenuService } from '@nebular/theme';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import {
  LoadVulnScanAction
} from '../../../store/actions/vulnscan.actions';
import { VulnerabilityScanService } from '../../../services/vulnerability-scan.service';
import { VulScanConfig } from '../../../services/vulScanConfig.service';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {
  debounceTime,
  distinctUntilChanged
} from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-vuln-scan-container',
  templateUrl: './vuln-scan-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vuln-scan-container.component.scss'],
})
export class VulScanContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('searchScheduleList', { static: true }) searchScheduleListElement: ElementRef;
  ticketSelected = false;
  results$: Observable<any>;
  private subjectKeyUp = new Subject<any>();
  
  constructor(
    // private menu: NbMenuService,
    private VulnerabilityScanService: VulnerabilityScanService,
    private vulScanConfig: VulScanConfig,
    private store: Store<any>,
    searchScheduleListElement: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.searchScheduleListElement = searchScheduleListElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.store.select(store => store.vulnScan.list).subscribe(payload => {

      if (payload) {
        this.vulnScanList = payload['VulnerabilityScan'];
      }
    });
    this.store.select(store => store.vulnScan.loadedVulnScan).subscribe(payload => {
      if (!payload) {
        const assetFilterData = {
          filters: {

          },
        };
        this.store.dispatch(new LoadVulnScanAction(assetFilterData));
      }
    });

    this.subjectKeyUp.pipe((debounceTime(1000))).subscribe((searchValue) => {
      this.getVulnScheduleListWithFilter(searchValue);
    })

  }

  getVulnScheduleListWithFilter(searchTxt) {
    const pFilterData = {
      filters: {
        searchKeyword: searchTxt,

      },
    };
    this.VulnerabilityScanService.getvulnerabilitylist(pFilterData).subscribe(payload => {
      this.vulnScanList = payload['VulnerabilityScan'];
    })

  }
  
  filterVulnScheduleList(event: any) {
    const searchKeyword = event.target.value;
    this.subjectKeyUp.next(searchKeyword);
  }

 
}
```